# How to get errors translated from Laravel with API (use AXIOS)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

I can retrieve data from the validator of Laravel. My application vue.js is multilingual. I wish I could recover the errors of Laravel but translated.

I'm trying to send the axios query with the `Accept-Language` headers

A log console of my request :

```
{url: "auth/login", method: "post", data: {…}, headers: {…}, baseURL: "http://myapp.test/api", …}
adapter: ƒ xhrAdapter(config)
baseURL: "http://myath.test/api"
data: "{"email":"jeremy@myapp.test","password":"password"}"
headers:
Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
Accept-Language: "en"
Content-Type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
```

We see that my request sends "Accept-Language".

But my errors are always returned in Laravel's default language

This is how I do with Nuxtjs :

```
export default async function ({ $axios }) {
 $axios.onRequest((config) => {
 console.log(config)
 config.headers.common['Accept-Language'] = 'en'
})
```

}

Do you have an idea? Can you explain to me?

Thank you !

Comment: Have you added the appropriate custom error messages to `resources/lang/{lang}/validation.php`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yes !